# How to use Bitcoin Testnet2

Tags: testnet

I am looking to mine bitcoins with ease. But, first, I want to know how can I access an earlier testnet (testnet2). I have future plans to do this. I need to know how to open it up on the command line and I will take it from there. Bitcoin testnet2 has been supressed by the developers and I am curious on how to use it.